# How can I use dropzone without using the class in the form

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js library for uploading multiple files using codeigniter and i basically want to have a div inside a form and call class="dropzone" in that div. But it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: you just want that div to display the files you put and then submit the whole form including inputs and those files when you click submit button . Am i right ?

Answer (score 2):

In that case you have to add this following way. See the documentation of dropzone http://www.dropzonejs.com/#create-dropzones-programmatically

```
<div class="dropzone" id="myId">
   <div class="fallback">
       <input id="files" multiple="true" name="files" type="file">
    </div>
</div>
```

And in script of any js file you have to include following code

```
<script>
$("div#myId").dropzone({ url: "/file/post" });
</script>
```